# Performance micro difference of attaching events to a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance

I was wondering about performance difference between :

```
this.BTN_LogIN.Click += new EventHandler(BTN_LogIN_Click);
```

**vs**

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="BTN_LogIN" onclick="BTN_LogIN_Click" >
```

I think the latter is using reflection at runtime to decide which functiuon to go , hence its slower.

is it right ?

Comment: Is this an actual issue for you?

Comment: In this case I would use the one which is easiest to read and find (imho the second one)

Comment: @oded If I can't answer that question to a work colleague  - so yes :)

Comment: @jgauffin the question is tagged for performance .. not"easyTorRead"

Comment: @RoyiNamir  take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WeakEvents.aspx

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Micro optimization is usually a larger performance bottleneck than code that is easy to read. Give that as an answer to your colleague. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, both will perform identically, since Asp.Net uses reflection to figure out which button was clicked in order to raise the appropriate click event.